# Laravel Sync Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get several options and several specifications for each of my products.

In order to get several values instead of one I had to make third tables named `product_suboptions` and `product_subspecifications` where it gets id of product and id of `options` + `subspecifications`

This is my create method:

```
$options = Option::all();
$suboptions = Suboption::all();
$specifications = Specification::all();
$subspecifications = Subspecification::all();
return view('admin.products.create', compact('options', 'suboptions', 'specifications', 'subspecifications'));
```

This is my store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
//.........

$product->save();
$product->suboptions()->sync($request->suboptions, false);
$product->subspecifications()->sync($request->subspecifications, false);

return ......//
}
```

This relations in my models:

`Product`

```
public function option(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class);
  }
  public function suboption(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Suboption::class);
  }
  public function specification(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Specification::class);
  }
  public function subspecification(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Subspecification::class);
  }
```

`Option`

```
public function products(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
  }
```

`Suboption`

```
public function products(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
  }
```

`Specification`

```
public function products(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
  }
```

`Subspecification`

```
public function products(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
  }
```

Now the problem is when i save product it returns this error

> BadMethodCallException
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::suboptions()

and only save my product but nothing in `product_suboptions` and `product_subspecifications` tables.

any idea?

Comment: you have `suboption`as a method in `product.php` but you are calling `suboptions`. Change `suboption` to `suboptions` and try again

Comment: @usrNotFound still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

The problem was in my form i was trying to get name such as `name="suboption_id[]"` which i had to get it like `name="suboptions[]"` now working perfectly.